# Linking a <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link a  element. I want it to be almost like a button where everything is linked, and with the hover effect I've made in the CSS. It is looking ok at the moment, except from it not beeing clickable or a link:)

Any tips?

You can see my site here http://sutterud2.eksaktlidenskap.no (scroll a bit down to see the grey boxes with text and images inside)

This is my html:

```
<a href="http://some-url.com"><div class="one-half first greybox">
<img src="http://sutterud2.eksaktlidenskap.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dummy-produktbilde.jpg"> </div></a>
```

And this is my css:

```
.greybox {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 4px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
}

.greybox:hover {
    border: 4px solid #ecebeb;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color: #ecebeb;
}
```

Comment: When i wrapped box on your page with `<a>` everything worked as it should. Are you sure you added `href` with an address to `<a>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect, you simply forgotten to add you `<a>` element around your `<div>` on the website.

**Current:**

```
<div class="one-half first greybox">
  <h2>Armbåndsur</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="http://sutterud2.eksaktlidenskap.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dummy-produktbilde.jpg">
    <br />
    Qhjkjh kjh kjh kjh kjh kjh khøhjlkjh jfgdfghdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd hgfd hgfdhfdhgfd hgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd g
</div>
```

- Non closed `<p>`
- Missing `<a>` to make your div clickable

**Should be:**

```
<a href="...">
  <div class="one-half first greybox">
    <h2>Armbåndsur</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="http://sutterud2.eksaktlidenskap.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dummy-produktbilde.jpg">
      <br />
      Qhjkjh kjh kjh kjh kjh kjh khøhjlkjh jfgdfghdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd hgfd hgfdhfdhgfd hgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd g
    </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Or better:**

```
<a href="..." class="one-half first greybox">
  <h2>Armbåndsur</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="http://sutterud2.eksaktlidenskap.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dummy-produktbilde.jpg">
    <br />
    Qhjkjh kjh kjh kjh kjh kjh khøhjlkjh jfgdfghdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfdhgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd hgfd hgfdhfdhgfd hgfd hgfd hgfd ghfd g
  </p>
</a>
```

Why using an extra div when you don't need it?

Comment: "you simply forgotten to add you A element arround your DIV" look again.

Comment: @Deuterium The `<a>` is here in the SO example, but **not** on the website.

Comment: LOL, my apologize. BTW: please edit the post to undo my downvote.